# How to retrieve values from Database in WordPress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm new to Database and I am hassling with it.

The structure of the affected tables are as follows:

**1) Table: wp_tdpp_commentmeta**

```
--------------------------------------------
meta_id   comment_id  meta_key  meta_value
--------------------------------------------
1           18         secretid   private
--------------------------------------------
2           19         secretid   public
--------------------------------------------
...
```

**2) Table: wp_tdpp_comments**

```
------------------------------------------------------
comment_ID   comment_post_ID .....  comment_content
------------------------------------------------------
18            14             ....   Comment Content for this comment_id
19            14             ...    ditto

...
------------------------------------------------------
```

The "wp_tdpp_commentmeta" is a custom comment meta field which will be entered by users when writing comments.

I'd like to check whether the value of 'meta_value' for the current comment_ID is "private" or "public."

Comment: Note that meta_id apparently serves no useful purpose, as there seems to be a perfectly good natural pk (comment_id,meta_key).

Comment: Look over a wordpress tutorial and use proper wp functions,what you have there is a hack waiting to happen.Start with https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts and https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta.As a general rule if you dont have custom tables added by a theme,if you are using the table names you are doing it wrong

Comment: @Mihai. Thanks a lot for the reference page. I will read it carefully.

Comment: @Strawberry. I resolved this issue with your help. (I thought your comment over and realized what you meant.) Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Great. If you like, you can post the answer and accept it, or remove the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to retrieve the values of the custom field by using "get_comment_meta()". Please refer to https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_meta for details on the "get_comment_meta" function.